# What is a Content Management Platform?

Tags: 7

Currently Drupal defines itself as a "Content Management Platform". My assumption is that they are trying to differentiate themselves from CMS which provide a much more specific goal, such as a wiki or pure blog.

I have found some research and other systems which also use the term but not a single definition.

Can anyone provide a noteworthy definition or provide one themselves which would match the current consensus? Do other broadly scoped CMS such as Joomla and WordPress fall into this category?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Jeff Eaton](http://www.lullabot.com/about/team/jeff-eaton) provides a pretty comprehensive post in [Understanding 8: Where Drupal Is and Where it's Going](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-8-where-drupal-and-where-its-going), where he discusses these differences (at least in Drupal terms).

Drupal as a Framework

> The foundation of that stack is the essential "web framework" code for
>   Drupal. It's the portion of Drupal that provides essential services
>   any web application would require. Rendering data into HTML and other
>   formats, identifying and loading plugins, handling HTTP requests and
>   responses, caching, database and storage access, and so on all live at
>   this layer...

Drupal as a Platform (i.e CMS)

> Moving up in the stack, we find the "building blocks" layer that Catch
>   referred to as the "Platform" in his blog post. This is where we begin
>   to encounter Drupal-specific approaches to CMS and web building
>   problems. The Entity system, users, nodes, taxonomy terms and
>   vocabularies, actions, roles and permissions, FieldAPI, text formats,
>   and our concept of "Blocks and regions" live here, and can be used to
>   assemble features and functionality. Reusable user interface tools and
>   UX components are also here: things like drag-and-drop tools, Drupal
>   7's Overlay mechanism, and so on are all reusable tools used to craft
>   usable interfaces.

These differences and more, are also covered in his DrupalCon London Presentation. [Product, Framework, or Platform? What They Mean, And Why You Should Care](http://london2011.drupal.org/conference/sessions/product-framework-or-platform-what-they-mean-and-why-you-should-care)

Essentially Drupal is both, a CMF and a CMS (and more) and why these discussions have come up recently in an effort for the community to define Drupal a bit more.

Comment: +1 Was writing the same thing buy you got there first and worded it better. Also nice with link for DC presentation.

Comment: "The idea of a platform is it’s a thing that lets you use products". I'm glad that I'm not the only one questioning the number of labels going around and what they mean. It's also good to hear that someone is actually working to define them further. The whole thing is kind of "fuzzy", that is, every type of content management system from MediaWiki to Drupal contains a bit of each element mentioned but CMS like Drupal are really starting to show a more and more of a resemblance to operating systems. Thanks!